# iOS How to reset UITableView's color after changed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm writing an iOS app that supports **Auto-Night theme**, and there is `UITableView` I need to work on night theme.

When the app enables night theme, I change the UITableView's background color, section header background color, and my customized cell's color.

My question is that when the app disables night theme, how to reset the **UITableView's background color** and the corresponding **section header background color**?

I tried to call `reloadData` method when disabling night theme, but the colors remain night theme.

I have to specifically set these colors to default to make it work, but somehow I feel is not the 'right' way to do it.

Is there any way to reset the `UITableView` to default colors? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is nothing wrong with setting the color back to original when you disable night mode.

However if you do want to be elegant about it you can set the color of the TableView by using a closure variable which will determine if Dark Mode is on or off and accordingly return a color.

```
var colorForTableView: (Bool) -> (UIColor) = { isDarkMode in

    let defaultColor = UIColor.white
    let darkColor = UIColor.black

    return isDarkMode ? darkColor : defaultColor
}
```

Usage:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = colorForTableView(isDarkMode)
```